# How do I read a file in Ruby using a specific script?

Tags: ruby, text-files, stdin, argv

I am doing a series of tutorials on how to code in Ruby. I want to read a .txt file using this formula:

```
filename = ARGV.first

prompt = "> "
txt = File.open(filename)

puts "Here's your file: #{filename}"
puts txt.read()

puts "I'll also ask you to type it again:"
print prompt
file_again = STDIN.gets.chomp()

txt_again = File.open(file_again)

puts txt_again.read()
```

The text file reads:

```
This is stuff I typed into a file. It is really cool stuff.
Lots and lots of fun to have in here.
```

The name for the text file is `ex15_sample.txt`. I tried with the above formula, and nothing seems to work. I have a hard understanding how to use both `ARGV` and `STDIN.gets.chomp`.

What should I do? I ask that you use the formula above; this stuff is a little confusing, so for now, just use the formula above.

Comment: What do you mean by "specific script"? Do you mean "encoding"? And what is a "formula"?

Comment: How are you running the program: what exactly are you typing on the command line? And when you say nothing seems to work, what exactly do you mean: are there error messages?

Comment: @Jorg See, I don't know a whole lot of terms regarding what it is I'm doing.  I'm a beginner...and I only know very basic things, so all of this is completely new to me.  But to answer your questions:  I don't know what I mean't by specific script since my question has been edited.  I think that encoding what I might be trying to do.  I say formula as in the one that says "ARGV.first, etc.. etc...  Like I said, completely new.

Comment: @FMc Well, where it says "filename = ARGV.first" I fill in the filename with "ex15_sample.txt" and it gives me error messages all the time.  So yes, every time I try to do something new, I just get error messages out of the yin yang.

Comment: @Jorg What I mean't by specific script is, the big script that reads "filename = ARGV.first, etc...etc.."  Sorry, I forgot about the main question above.

Answer (score 2):

The script works.  You're not explaining how you're trying to run the script or what errors you're seeing, so it's a bit hard to help you.

If you have a text file named `ex15_sample.txt` in the same directory as your script (let's call it `script.rb`), and if you have Ruby set up properly, then if you run it with

```
$ ruby script.rb ex15_sample.txt
```

everything should work fine.

If you're trying to change the first line to always use `ex15_sample.txt`, be sure to put it in quotes:

```
filename = "ex15_sample.txt" # Without the quotes, you'll get an error.
```

Again, it's hard to help you without knowing exactly how you're running the script or what errors you're getting.

**Update:** I seems your issue is that you aren't clear on how to run a Ruby script.  The simplest way is to, at your system's command prompt, type `ruby` then a space, then the name of the file with a Ruby script in it.  If your script is in a file named `script.rb`, you would type `ruby script.rb`. That won't work if your script is in a file with a different name.  If the script is in a file named `read-a-file.rb`, then you need to type `ruby read-a-file.rb`.

This particular script wants a command line argument after the file name.  If the text file you want to read is in a file named `ex15_sample.txt`, then you need to type that after the script name.  In the previous example, the command would become `ruby read-a-file.rb ex15_sample.txt`.  That will only work if the files are in the same directory (a.k.a. folder).

Comment: Ok, lemme try it, and I'll come back to ya with my error messages.

Comment: Well, lemme ask you this question.  When you say, if you run it with $ ruby script.rb ex15_sample.txt that it should work, what exactly do you mean?  Do you mean from the command prompt?  Like for ex: I type in irb, then type in what you put above and then should I get no error messages.  Maybe that's the problem...maybe I dunno what to do to begin with.  Basically I'm just trying to get Ruby to read that .txt file, that's all I'm really doing.

Comment: What floors me too is, I didn't have a problem with any of the tutorials up until this point.  I don't get it.

Comment: Usin the script as it stands, trying to get the file name from `ARGV`, doesn't really make sense in irb.  You would type `ruby script.rb ex15_sample.txt` instead of typing `irb` at the command prompt if you want to run the script in a file called `script.rb`.  If you just want Ruby to read the file from within irb, you could just do `File.read('ex15_sample.txt')`.

Comment: Well...lemme type in just ruby script.rb ex15_sample.txt in the command prompt and see what happens.

Comment: It says "ruby: no such file or directory -- script.rb <LoadError>

Comment: That's telling you that you don't have a file named `script.rb`.  You should type the actual name of your script there.

Comment: Oh...

So, if that's the case, do I just make a new file labeled script.rb and put the .txt file in it and THEN run the script again?  Explanation?  You have to speak to me as if I'm an alien and I know nothing about computers (even though in real life, I'm sure aliens would know plenty about them lol).

Comment: If you put the text file into `script.rb` and tried to run it, it wouldn't go smoothly, because that text file is not valid Ruby. I've updated my answer explaining as plainly as I can how to run a Ruby script and how to add a command line argument.

Comment: Ok Darshan, I read your update, and the first part of the script ran well.  I figured out what the problem was.  I was typing this in the command prompt, but I was typing this in the C: directory, so I went to the correct directory labeled under "Ruby200-x64" and I went to the "bin" part, and the first half was ok.

Now, when it asked me to type it again...wait a sec, lemme try something.  Gimme a sec.

Comment: **SOLVED**

I figured it out.  Ok, so here's how to do it.  First off, I have to make sure I'm in the same directory the .txt files are that should also be in the same directory as the .rb files are.  

So, I did that, and typed in both the .txt and .rb files and I came up with my text file and it showed up just fine.  When they ask me to type it a second time, I just type in my .txt filename and the text appeared again.  THANK YOU FOR YOUR PATIENCE!

Comment: Happy to help.  Since you're brand new here, I'll point out that it would be appropriate to mark this answer as the accepted answer at this point (unless you feel it doesn't adequately address your question).